# Contact Form 7 + WooCommerce - Save form data in orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I have following problem: [orders page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9rwP.png)

I have a Contact Form 7 with 2 dropdown options for ordering tickets for an event, no user registration. This works fine but it doesn't save any form data in the "orders" page of woocommerce like the included image, which makes keeping track of orders difficult. In additional settings of the contact form I have following:

```
on_sent_ok: "switch(document.forms[0].elements["registration_type"].value){case "Normal Registration": location.replace('url/checkout-3/?clear-cart&add-to-cart=325&quantity=1');break;case "Presenter Registration": location.replace('url/checkout-3/?clear-cart&add-to-cart=327&quantity=1');break;};"
```

Which inserts the order in to Woocommerce but I need customer data like name adress and email too. Unfortunately I am not efficient with this type of code yet, can anyone bump me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use A CF7 for ordering a product? You seem to take this from the wrong end. Please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: The CF7 saves the form data in Contact Form DB, which was requested to later be able to export to CSV. on_sent adds the product in woocommerce checkout, to then use wirecard which was also requested. The step missing is saving field data from CF7 and inserting it in the orders overview of woocommerce.

Comment: I see. What you basically need to do is to hook on `wpcf7_mail_sent` to save the form data in session then save them later in custom fields when order is created (using `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` action) and display them on the order page using meta boxes. If you don't know how to proceed I will ellaborate an answer.

Comment: Would be great if you could elaborate and show a sample code and where to implement it. This isnt my strength at all, thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can save your CF7 data in session, in order to save them later with your order (considering that the order isn't created yet at this point). You can make use of the `wpcf7_mail_sent` action that is triggered when the mail is sent. *Please note that all the following code take place in your theme functions.php.*

```
function wc_wpcf7_mail_sent_function($contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if($submission) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        WC()->session->set('cf7_posted_data', $posted_data);
    }
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wc_wpcf7_mail_sent_function');
```

This use the Woocommerce Session class [`WC_Session`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session.html).

Then save the data in custom fields when the order is processed:

```
function wc_save_cf7_data_to_order($order_id) {
    $posted_data = base64_encode(serialize(WC()->session->get('cf7_posted_data')));
    if(!empty($posted_data)) {
        add_post_meta($order_id, 'cf7_posted_data', $posted_data);
        WC()->session->__unset('cf7_posted_data');
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'wc_save_cf7_data_to_order', 10, 1);
```

This will save all the CF7 form data in a serialized string, stored in base64 to avoid any decoding issue.

Last, you need to add a [meta box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) to show the form data on the order page:

```
function wc_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'order_tickets',
        __('Contact form data', 'your-theme'),
        'wc_print_order_cf7_data_callback',
        'shop_order'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wc_add_meta_box');
```

Then display the data:

```
function print_order_tickets_callback($post) {
    $posted_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cf7_posted_data', true);
    if(!empty($tickets)) {
        $posted_data = unserialiaze(base64_decode($posted_data));
        foreach($posted_data as $key => $data) {
            echo '<b>', $key, ' : </b> ', $data, '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I limit this functionality to one form ?

Comment: @FDI A bit late but you can check the data in `$posted_data` if it has the field keys of your form (maybe use an hidden input form for this, like a "save_in_session" field).

Comment: There are some issues with your code - 'wc_print_order_cf7_data_callback'),  has a rogue ).  And wordpress is not liking the public function.  I tried the code on a form and the form hangs on submission